# Jasper reports are not printing out using netbeans 8.1(java Coding)

Tags: javascript, java

[i write code for button which will print out the report by using jasper report but when i run the program "not supported yet" error is coming in the output.

How can i resolve it so that it will print my jasper report,the snapshot of coding and error is given here.

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste in the code here.

Comment: as text, not as image!

Comment: try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mylogin","root","1234");
                
                    
                String report="C:\\Users\\Aamir\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\MainLoginSit\\src\\Reports\\empfamilyReport.jrxml";
                JasperReport jr;
                jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
                JasperPrint jp=JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,null,con);
                JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);
                con.close();

Comment: }
            catch(Exception e){
        
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }